# Cargar elements al azar dentro de GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy desarrollando una especie de candy crush (Bejeweled) en [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio). Por ahora tengo hecho un en el XML un `GridLayout` de 8 columnas x 8 filas con los elementos que serian las "Gemas" que son de distintos colores.

¿Como deberia hacer para cuando inicie la aplicación mis elementos se ubiquen de manera *Random* en el `GridLayout`?

Dejo el codigo que tengo hecho por ahora, les dejo una parte porque no me deja ponerlo todo:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    android:src="@drawable/blue"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/green"
    android:src="@drawable/green"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/orange"
    android:src="@drawable/orange"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/purple"
    android:src="@drawable/purple"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/yellow"
    android:src="@drawable/yellow"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">

</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/red"
    android:src="@drawable/red"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">

</ImageView>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias generar los `ImageView` dinamicamente al momento de cargar tu vista.

Comment: No entiendo como hacer referencia a las opsiciones del grid layout. Yo pensaba en usar una matriz en done las pos [i] [j] seria la posicion de la imagen que voy a insertar aleatoriamente. Para esto deberia de declarar un random, pero no sabria si seria lo correcto

Comment: Podrais subir el resto del codigo para visualizar bien ?

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener una matriz de 8x8 donde pongas una representacion de las gemas y despues desde la visual cargar dinamicamente las imagenes de las gemas.
Yo utilicé esto en un juego de damas que implementé y me funcionó de lo mejor

Comment: Para mejorar la respuesta, puedes poner un fragmento del codigo donde demuestres la propuesta que hiciste.